# Docker Class.forName doesn't find class

Tags: java, class, docker, reflection, classpath

I'm running a server in a docker image openjdk:8-jdk-slim.
Inside this server, using spring boot, I receive from the frontend a protobuf file, compile it and add the generated class to the classpath in runtime. I then proceed to use java reflection to get the added class, with the method Class.forName().

Outside of docker, when running in my pc, it works like a charm. However, when I run in docker when I try to access using the method Class.forName(), with the same class name I use when not in docker, it doesn't find the class.
Is there something that I am missing because it is docker?

**Edit for more information:**

I'm running a maven build inside docker. What I have in this specific operation is an endpoint that receives a byte array, which corresponds to a protobuf file. I "construct" a file with this byte array, save it in a specific folder. I proceed to compile it with the protoc compiler, which generates a .java file, which I save in a specific folder. This folder corresponds to a package, which we will call "xxx.yyy.zzz". 
When I try to add the class to the classpath, using this code -

```
File newClass = new File(relativePath);
URL url = newClass.toURI().toURL();
URLClassLoader classLoader = (URLClassLoader)ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
Method newMethod = URLClassLoader.class.getDeclaredMethod("addURL", URL.class);
newMethod.setAccessible(true);
newMethod.invoke(classLoader, url);
```

- I provide the relativePath to the .class file but it isn't added to the classpath. I know that the .class file is generated in the correct way and is saved in the specific folder.

Comment: It should work the same.  What assumptions do you have about where things are put?  You can always exec a shell and look at the state of docker instance.

Comment: I know the protobuf file is compiled and the class is saved in the correct directory. I executed a shell to verify that. The generated class is inside the target directory, in the generated-sources folder, and belongs to a package. For example, the package is xxx.yyy.zzz, so I'm calling the Class.forName() with the class name "xxx.yyy.zzz.ClassName". The problem is that it says that doesn't find the class when I know that the class is there. Can there be something to do with the CLASSPATH?

Comment: This sounds like you are running a full maven build inside Docker.  Your question needs additional information and attention.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I edited the post, adding more information. Thank you for the help, btw

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that your relative path is correct?  Try printing out the absolute path  for `newClass`.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I verified and the path is correct. Even in docker, the path is correct.

Comment: When you really “provide the relativePath to the .java file”, then it’s clear that it can’t work. You need to provide a path to compiled .class files. Besides that, you should rethink your approach anyway, as starting with Java 9, hacking the system class loader in this way will not work at all.

Comment: I noticed that mistake yesterday and already corrected. I now add to the classpath the .class, that is compiled from the .java. However the problems remains. @Holger What way do you recommend?

Comment: The class path consists of *directories* resp. jar files so when you say you “provide the relativePath to the .class file”, there is everything wrong, as you need the *absolute* path to the *parent directory* of the class file resp. its package directories. But you said, “it works like a charm” outside of docker, so it is not clear. Anyway, as said, such hacking will fail starting with Java 9, so I recommend finding a different way to use dynamic class loading with docker. I don’t know anything about docker so I can't tell you how.